# Using A variable accorss different classes. Java Android

Tags: java, android, variables

I have two class files. One which creates and stores a value in a string (PINString).
The second class file uses the variable to show in a textView. as shown below:
Currently the calue of the variable PINString isnt being passed through

First

```
  {


        //
        int randomPIN = (int)(Math.random()*9000)+1000;

        //
        String PINString = String.valueOf(randomPIN);

         Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),verification.class);
     i.putExtra("PINString", PINString);//transfer string
     startActivity(i);

    }
```

Second

```
           public void onClick(View view) 

           {

            String PINString;

            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            PINString = bundle.getString("SMSDemo.PINString");



               TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

               textView2.setText(PINString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass your variable as "PinString":

```
i.putExtra("PINString", PINString);//transfer string
```

So, instead of this:

```
PINString = bundle.getString("SMSDemo.PINString");
```

Use

```
PINString = bundle.getString("PINString");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
 i.putExtra("PINString", PINString);
 // key is PINString
```

The keys must match. Use `PINString` while you get the string also

```
PINString = bundle.getString("PINString");
```

Also follow java naming conventions while naming vairables